# How to find if any jar is using a deprecated class

Tags: java, debugging, spring-boot

I was migrating from Spring boot 1.3 to 1.5 and am getting a class not found error for ServletRegistrationBean.
Which is expected as this has been deprecated.
What am not able to understand is which jar is causing this?
I would like to understand how can debug it further?
Basically how to walk through jars to see which class is getting loaded at the time of failure and where it is from so I can correct my dependencies

I have used couple of tools to walk through the jars and find dependencies but that did not help me

```
    org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerSyntheticBeanIfMissing(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:148)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.ail.myaccount.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
[INFO] [] [] 2017-06-09_12:14:59.184 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@485e36bc: startup date [Fri Jun 09 12:14:53 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[WARN] [] [] 2017-06-09_12:14:59.188 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@485e36bc: startup date [Fri Jun 09 12:14:53 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.ail.myaccount.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:20)
[ERROR] [] [] 2017-06-09_12:14:59.189 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@485e36bc: startup date [Fri Jun 09 12:14:53 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.ail.myaccount.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:20)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1189)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:862)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:848)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:834)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:788)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.ail.myaccount.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 24 more
:bootRun FAILED
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you simply left both versions on the classpath, APIs are getting mixed up. Double check your classpath for duplicated libraries

Also please reffer to this github issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8186

Comment: I checked the jar. All I have was spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
I used tattletale to check.
I checked for the class which is throwing exception, even this class was no where to be found (org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean)

Comment: Did you include org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web ??? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.3.RELEASE

Comment: @AnunaySinha checkout the github issue i have included into my answer

Comment: I have spring boot starter web (1.5.3)
I have already checked this issue. I am not able to figure out how to identify which class is being loaded and from which jar that is causing this problem.